# Poisson distribution with mean 7.8 - find modal value

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

The discrete random variable X has a poisson distribution with mean $x$. What is an expression for the modal value of X if $x$ = 7.8.

What is a modal value? Does it mean mode? I've never come across this type of question - please help!!!! Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is the mode. For a Poisson distribution, you have a direct correspondance with the mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Mean

Comment: How do you calculate modal value for poisson distribution?!? Is there a formula?

Comment: See above. (In general, for questions such as basic properties of probability distributions, Wikipedia or WolframAlpha are a good pair of first places to look at.)

Answer (score 1):

The usual notation for the mean of a Poisson distribution is $\lambda$ (small Greek letter corresponding to 'ell'). I will use that, instead of $x,$ which might be confusing.

It is important to distinguish between the *mode* (point at which
the maximum value of a function is obtained) and *modal value* (value of the function at the mode).

The mode of $Pois(\lambda = 7.8)$ is 7. That is, if $X \sim Pois(7.8),$ then $P(X = 7)$ has
is the greatest probability for any single point of the distribution.
The modal value is $P(X = 7) =  0.1428021.$

In general, for noninteger $\lambda$, the mode is at the next
integer below $\lambda.$

For integer $\lambda$ two values
share the largest probability. For example, if $\lambda = 7,$
then $P(X = 6) = P(X = 7) =  0.1490028,$ and all other values of $X$ have smaller probabilities . Textbooks vary on terminology here: some say
there is no mode (having defined the mode as to be necessarily unique) and others say there is a 'double mode' at the two values.

For integer $\lambda$ the 'double mode' is at $\lambda$ and the
next smaller integer.

For a mathematical proof, let 
$$f(k) = P(X = k|\lambda) = \exp(-\lambda)\lambda^k/k! = e^{-\lambda}\,\lambda^k/k!,$$
for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots.$

Then look at the ratio $f(k+1)/f(k)$ to see where it changes
from being greater than 1 to less than 1. (It is not difficult
because there is lots of cancellation in the ratio.) Many maximization 
questions in math are answered by calculus, but we are dealing
with discrete $k$ here, so methods of calculus do not apply.

Wikipedia does give the mode of a Poisson distribution, but
in terms of 'ceiling' and 'floor' notation that may not be
familiar to you. That is good notation to know, and you might
want to look up the definitions.